# How to insert serial numbers for every object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a javaScript game of housie/bingo game. I used the library npm tambola-generator which returns auto generated tickets.

The server side process generates an array similar to this one ...

```
[{
  "_entries": [[0,17,0,0,41,53,0,78,86], [4,0,0,35,0,58,67,80,0]/*, [ ... ] */],
}, {
  "_entries": [[0,16,23,0,41,51,0,0,88], [2,20,0,31,43,56,0,0,0]/*, [ ... ] */],
}, {
  "_entries": [[0,0,23,33,0,51,0,73,87], [1,0,0,35,42,58,68,0,0]/*, [ ... ] */],
}, {
  // ... more items like that ...
}]
```

I want each ticket to feature a serial number which should be equal to a ticket items's array index but starting with the base of `1` instead of `0`.

How does one include such a ticket number so that I can manage tickets for players?

I am just a beginner I couldn't solve it out. The target structure of the above example code should look like the following one ...

```
[{
  "ticketNum": 1,
  "_entries": [[0,17,0,0,41,53,0,78,86], [4,0,0,35,0,58,67,80,0]/*, [ ... ] */],
}, {
  "ticketNum": 2,
  "_entries": [[0,16,23,0,41,51,0,0,88], [2,20,0,31,43,56,0,0,0]/*, [ ... ] */],
}, {
  "ticketNum": 3,
  "_entries": [[0,0,23,33,0,51,0,73,87], [1,0,0,35,42,58,68,0,0]/*, [ ... ] */],
}, {
  // ... more items like that ...
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for achieving this task.

```js
const entries = [{
  "_entries": [
    [0, 17, 0, 0, 41, 53, 0, 78, 86],
    [4, 0, 0, 35, 0, 58, 67, 80, 0]
  ],
}, {
  "_entries": [
    [0, 16, 23, 0, 41, 51, 0, 0, 88],
    [2, 20, 0, 31, 43, 56, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
}, {
  "_entries": [
    [0, 0, 23, 33, 0, 51, 0, 73, 87],
    [1, 0, 0, 35, 42, 58, 68, 0, 0]
  ],
}];

const tcktEntries = entries.map((entry, index) => {
  return {
    ticketNum: index + 1,
    ...entry
  };
});

console.log({
  tcktEntries
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%!important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: It's giving array [{"ticketNum":1,"entry":{"_entries":[[1,13,0,36,50,0,0,78,0],[7,19,25,37,0,0,0,0,82],[0,0,0,38,0,56,68,80,87]]}}   So how to remove the  _entries from entry

Comment: It should not add an additional entry object. Please see the updated answer and compare the code that you have written with it. Make sure you use the spread operator (...) as shown in the snippet in the answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much Sir. I didn't know  about the spread operator.